# How can I select an ISO file to use with Cubic?

Tags: filemanager, customizer

I just installed Bionic Beaver this morning, fresh install on my HP laptop. I selected the option to *not* have all the extra stuff like Rythmbox installed.
First thing I did was install synaptic, then nemo file manager, then cubic. Then I started downloading the Bionic Beaver Desktop ISO to use with Cubic. My connection is too slow, so I decided I'd try to customize the mini.iso provided on the Alternative Downloads page. (Only 64mb for Bionic!)

Now in Cubic, I open the program, choose a project directory, then it takes me to a screen where it wants me to select an original ISO. I click a button labeled "select," then navigate to my Downloads folder and click mini.iso. Now when I click the select button, or enter, or double click the ISO file, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? I've restarted multiple times and can't select any ISO files in my selection menu. Should I uninstall my file manager and install a different one? I think it's using whatever comes stock and not nemo... I just can't figure out how to actually select the ISO. This seems like a ridiculous issue to be having and asking about... but I'm totally stuck.

Here's a screenshot. How do I proceed from here?

[stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wL3g.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mini.iso doesn't have `filesystem.squashfs` on it. `filesystem.squashfs`is actually a compressed version of the OS that will be installed, and this is what Cubic allows you to modify. The mini.iso doesn't have this (which is why it is so small), and it downloads required files during the install process. So you would not use Cubic to modify mini.iso.